# Using SaltStack to create a Mysql database

Tags: mysql, vagrant, salt-stack, devops

I am using SaltStack (with vagrant)/Ubuntu 12.04.

My goal is to install Mysql, create a database and a user and grant all privileges.

What's wrong with this SLS file?

```
mysql_setup:
  debconf.set:
    - name: mysql-server
    - data:
        'mysql-server/root_password': {'type': 'string', 'value': '{{ pillar['database']['password'] }}'}
        'mysql-server/root_password_again': {'type': 'string', 'value': '{{ pillar['database']['password'] }}'}

mysql-server:
  pkg:
    - installed
    - require:
      - debconf: mysql_setup

mysql-base:
  mysql_database.present:
    - name: owncloud
  mysql_user.present:
    - name: owncloud
    - password: pass
  mysql_grants.present:
    - database: owncloud.*
    - grant: ALL PRIVILEGES
    - user: owncloud
```

I had this error:

```
[INFO    ] All specified answers are already set
[INFO    ] Completed state [mysql-server] at time 14:48:13.611204
[INFO    ] Running state [mysql-server] at time 14:48:13.644547
[INFO    ] Executing state pkg.installed for mysql-server
[INFO    ] Package mysql-server is already installed.
[INFO    ] Completed state [mysql-server] at time 14:48:13.695092
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded mysql_database.mod_init
[INFO    ] Running state [owncloud] at time 14:48:13.702359
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded mysql_database.present
[ERROR   ] State 'mysql_database.present' was not found in SLS 'mysql'

[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded mysql_user.mod_init
[INFO    ] Running state [owncloud] at time 14:48:13.710744
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded mysql_user.present
[ERROR   ] State 'mysql_user.present' was not found in SLS 'mysql'

[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded mysql_grants.mod_init
[INFO    ] Running state [mysql-base] at time 14:48:13.733003
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded mysql_grants.present
[ERROR   ] State 'mysql_grants.present' was not found in SLS 'mysql'
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what @Utah_Dave suggests, you also might need the `python-mysqldb` APT package as well as the `mysql` pip package, and you need connection information, either in your minion config or provided to the state, possibly like so:

```
foo_db:
  mysql_database.present:
    - name: {{ pillar['SQL_DATABASE'] }}
    - connection_host: {{ pillar['SQL_HOST'] }}
    - connection_user: {{ pillar['SQL_ROOT_USER'] }}
    - connection_pass: {{ pillar['SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'] }}
    - require:
      - pip: mysql
```

Future states can reuse the connection information with `use:` like so:

```
sql_app_user:
  mysql_user.present:
    - name: {{ pillar['SQL_APP_USER'] }}
    - password: {{ pillar['SQL_APP_PASSWORD'] }}
    - host: '%'
    - use:
      - mysql_database: foo_db
```

This is documented for [salt.modules.mysql](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.mysql.html#module-salt.modules.mysql). To install the other dependencies:

```
server_pkgs:
  pkg:
    - installed
    - pkgs:
      - python-dev
    - refresh: True

mysql_python_pkgs:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - libmysqlclient-dev
      - mysql-client
      - python-mysqldb
    - require:
      - pkg: server_pkgs

python-pip:
  pkg:
    - installed
    - refresh: False

mysql:
  pip.installed:
    - require:
      - pkg: python-pip
      - pkg: mysql_python_pkgs
```

This is an abridged version of my own states for a particular project, so it might not be the minimal things you need, but it definitely works.

Comment: `Comment: The following requisites were not found: require:pip: mysql`

Comment: That was left as an "exercise for the reader" :)

I'll update my answer to add that, for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but it kept popping up, when I was googling the error:

> Could not LazyLoad mysql.version: 'mysql' **virtual** returned False: The mysql execution module cannot be loaded: neither MySQLdb nor PyMySQL is available.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and the thing that solved it for me was installing the package

> python3-mysqldb

Appearently both python 2.7 and 3 was installed and salt was using 3 and the package python-mysqldb was only for 2.7.

I hope this will help anyone else landing on this question with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work the second time you run the state? Or after restarting the salt-minion daemon? If so, it's because the mysql_* states aren't aware that the mysql server has been installed.

You can see here that the `mysql_grants` state requires that the `mysql.grant_exists` function be loaded in Salt already.  https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/1fb606ef6beffecc3e34f18b9ce189db4fe4292f/salt/states/mysql_grants.py#L52

Try adding `- reload_modules: true` to your mysql-server state like this:

```
mysql-server:
  pkg:
    - installed
    - require:
      - debconf: mysql_setup
    - reload_modules: True
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to do this, have the same problem. I will keep you updated.